# Redirect and Render using Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

When I hit my api I want to redirect my url from `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/token/aaa.bbb.ccc` to `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/messages/:id`. I also want to render my `message` view

Code:

```
app.get('/token/:id' , (req, res) => {
  var decoded = jwt.verify(req.params.id, 'blabla');
  Message.findById(decoded.messageId, (err, message) => {
    if (err) res.json({error: err})
    res.render('message', {message})
  })
})
```

Here, I successfully render my `message` view but the URL for the below api is still `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/token/aaa.bbb.ccc` and not `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/messages/:id`

Another attempt:

```
app.get('/token/:id' , (req, res) => {
  var decoded = jwt.verify(req.params.id, 'blabla');

  Message.findById(decoded.messageId, (err, message) => {
    if (err) res.json({error: err})
    res.redirect('/messages/'+message._id)
  })
})
```

Now, the URL is `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/messages/:id` but the `message` view is not rendered. A JSON is rendered that displays the message

How do I redirect to `https://myapp.herokuapp.com/messages/:id` and also render the `message` view?

Comment: Does `/token/:id` get requested through a direct browser-request, or through an XHR ("AJAX") request?

Comment: Literally just from a link`<a target="_blank" href="https://myapi.com/token/theID">click the link</a>`

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if my answer would work (it won't when it's being requested through XHR). The `res.json({ error : err })` is a bit weird when it's being requested as a regular browser request, though, sounds like you'd want to render an error page there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first redirect:

```
app.get('/token/:id' , (req, res) => {
  var decoded = jwt.verify(req.params.id, 'blabla');

  Message.findById(decoded.messageId, (err, message) => {
    if (err) return res.json({error: err}); // see @partycoder's answer
    res.redirect('/messages/'+message._id)
  })
})
```

Next, you need to adjust the route handler for `/messages/:id`. Right now, it sounds like it's only used for XHR requests, so it will always return JSON. You can add a check to see if the request is an XHR-request or not, and either return JSON (for XHR) or a rendered template (for non-XHR):

```
app.get('/messages/:id', (req, res) => {
  ...
  if (req.xhr) {
    return res.json(...);
  } else {
    return res.render(...);
  }
});
```

([documentation for `req.xhr`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.xhr), be aware that the method on which this is based is not foolproof)

However, perhaps it's better to use content negotiation, where the client explicitly tells your server what format the response should be. The upside of this is that it's much more explicit, the downside is that you may have to change some client-side code. Documentation here: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.format